# Create a column wiget in flutter with the top item to be fixed and the rest to be scrolable

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a web app with flutter and I want to fix the top part of my body to serve as a navigation menu. But i could not get the rest of the body items to scroll, I have tried to wrap it with SingleChildScrollView but its throwing the below error.

> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
> This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

Below is the code i used,

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      Material(
        elevation: 10,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 50,),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Text("Brand", style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 26,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text("Articles",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text("Messages",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text("Books",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text("About",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                  Text("Give",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
            ),
            Icon(Icons.search),
            SizedBox(width: 10,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: `Column[TopNavMenu, Expanded > SingleChuldScrollView>Column[bla bla bla]]`

Answer (score 0):

As @[pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) suggested wrapping the SingleChildScrollView in Expanded widget will work.

```
body: Column(
children: [
  Material(
    elevation: 10,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: 10,),
        Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 50,),
            SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Text("Brand", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Text("Articles",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              Text("Messages",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              Text("Books",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              Text("About",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              Text("Give",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
        ),
        Icon(Icons.search),
        SizedBox(width: 10,)
      ],
    ),
  ),
  Expanded(
   SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
         Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',width: 200,),
       ],
     ),
   ),
  ),
],
```

),